# json PUT request

Tags: iphone, json, object

I'm sending JSON PUT request. I'm using JSONKIT. I'm not sure about how to convert dictionary to JSON data?

I want a equivalent method to JSONREPRESNTATION(JSON parser) in JSONKIT. sample code is as follows.

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[jsonDict setObject:@"linkedin-html" forKey:@"contentType"];

  [jsonDict setObject:@"dfdfdf" forKey:@"body"];

  NSString *jsonRequest = [jsonDict JSONData];  // doubt line

  NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]]; 

  [self setHTTPBody:requestData];

 [self setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  

  [self setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Answer (score 0):

id json = [arrayOne JSONString];

Available at, https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/blob/master/README.md